# SQL Cross Join error The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to return a few rows from my tables Jobs, but also the next due date from the table JobProducts (where each JobProduct has a due date).

I have the following so far

```
SELECT  J.CustomerID,  J.JobID, J.Status, 
J.Deleted, J.JobNo, Customers.CompanyName AS [Company], 
J.DateCreated AS [Date Created], derivedtbl_1.DueDate AS [Due Date] 
FROM Jobs  J
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Customers ON J.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT   TOP (1) DueDate, JobProductID, JobID, ProductID, DepartmentID 
FROM      JobProducts AS JobProducts_1 
WHERE    JobProducts_1.JobID = J.JobID 
ORDER BY DueDate) 
AS derivedtbl_1
```

but I get the error 
    The multi-part identifier "J.JobID" could not be bound.

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error seems to be from SQL Server. I think that you are confusing `CROSS JOIN` (wich is a cartesian product) with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  J.CustomerID,  
        J.JobID, 
        J.Status, 
        J.Deleted, 
        J.JobNo, 
        Customers.CompanyName AS [Company], 
        J.DateCreated AS [Date Created], 
        derivedtbl_1.DueDate AS [Due Date] 
FROM Jobs  J
LEFT JOIN Customers 
    ON J.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) DueDate, 
                           JobProductID, 
                           JobID, 
                           ProductID, 
                           DepartmentID 
            FROM JobProducts AS JobProducts_1 
            WHERE JobProducts_1.JobID = J.JobID 
            ORDER BY DueDate) 
AS derivedtbl_1
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try changing the cross join to cross apply

```
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT   TOP (1) DueDate, JobProductID, JobID, ProductID, DepartmentID 
FROM      JobProducts AS JobProducts_1 
WHERE    JobProducts_1.JobID = J.JobID 
ORDER BY DueDate)
```